# jQuery issue getting error -> Cannot read property 'match' of null

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        var searchField = $('#search').val();
        if(searchField.length >=3 )
        {

            var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");

            $.get('products.json', function(data) 
            {
                var output = '<ul class="searchresults">';
                $(data).each(function(key, val)
                {
                    var name = val.name;
                    if( name.match(myExp) != -1)
                    {
                        output += '<li>' + val.name + '</li>';
                    }

                });
                output += '</ul>';
                alert(output)
                $('#update').html(output);
            }); //get 
        }
    });
});
```

I have try to everything but not getting out of this error.
i have tried with .search and .test but still the same. any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What is there in `products.json` post that please

Comment: It contain very heavy data

Comment: `if( name && name.match(myExp) != -1) ...`

Comment: Thanks it works.

Comment: Maybe you need to fix the JSON file so that `name` isn't null.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        var searchField = $('#search').val();
        if(searchField.length >=3 ){

            var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");

            $.get('products.json', function(data) {

                var output = '<ul class="searchresults">';
                $(data).each(function(key, val){

                    var name = val.name;
                    if(name && name.toString().match(myExp)['index'] != -1){
                        output += '<li>' + val.name + '</li>';
                    }

                });
                output += '</ul>';

                alert(output)
                $('#update').html(output);
            }); //get 
        }
    });
});
```